# li element background colors and overflow scrolling

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I created a simple html source, and applied a small CSS style sheet to it:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
}
pre {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #888; 
    font-family: Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;
    color: #000;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto; 
}
pre li { white-space: pre; }

ol { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;  /* IE indents via margin-left */
     color: #979797; background: #E3E3E3; }
.li1 { background: #F5F5F5 }
.li2 { background: #eee }
```

I have an ordered list inside a pre-formatted tag.  Every other list element is either given the class attribute `li1` or `li2` (the purpose of which is to alternate the colors).  The list elements need the `white-space: pre` because the white space before and after the text node is important.  The `pre` is to be 80% of the containing element (which ends up being 80% of the window's width).  In the event of overflow in the x dimension, I want scrolling.

I did all this in the above CSS, and it *almost* works.  The issue I am having is that the background colors of the list elements don't extend with the content.  They seem to be capped to the original width of the `pre` and/or ol `element` as demonstrated in the following picture where I scroll all the way right as possible:

[image: List Element background colors don't extend]

I tinkered with the CSS for a while, but I cannot determine the root cause for this or the fix.  Looking for some advice on this one, thanks.

Complete source with the issue is as below, NOTE: to would-be editors of the below code the `pre` element is intended to be on a single line as it's pre-formatted text, and formatting it otherwise would change things.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test Site</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html {
    width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    pre {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid #888; 
        font-family: Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;
        color: #000;
        width: 80%;
        overflow: auto; 
    }
    pre li { white-space: pre; }

    ol { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;  /* IE indents via margin-left */
         color: #979797; background: #E3E3E3; }
    .li1 { background: #F5F5F5 }
    .li2 { background: #eee }
    </style>
</head>

<body>


<pre class="php"><ol><li class="li1">pre a &#123; text-decoration: none &#125;</li><li class="li2">pre a:hover &#123; background: #C8C8C8 }</li><li class="li1">pre li &#123; white-space: pre; &#125;</li><li class="li2">&nbsp;</li><li class="li1">.php ol &#123; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;  /* IE indents via margin-left */</li><li class="li2">          color: #979797; background: #E3E3E3; }</li><li class="li1">&nbsp;</li><li class="li2">&nbsp;</li><li class="li1">&nbsp;</li><li class="li2">.php .li1 &#123; background: #F5F5F5 }</li><li class="li1">.php .li2 &#123; background: #eee }</li><li class="li2">&nbsp;</li><li class="li1">&nbsp;</li><li class="li2">.php .st0  &#123; color: #C0C } /* string content */</li><li class="li1">.php .st_h &#123; color: #F0C } /* string content single quoted */</li><li class="li2">.php .sy0  &#123; color: #000 } /* semi-colon, operators */ </li><li class="li1">.php .br0  &#123; color: #000 } /* parens */</li><li class="li2">.php .kw2  &#123; color: #00F } /* php tags */</li><li class="li1">.php .sy1  &#123; color: #00F } /* php tags */</li><li class="li2">.php .nu0  &#123; color: #F00 } /* numbers */</li><li class="li1">.php .kw3  &#123; color: #096 } /* core language functions */</li><li class="li2">.php .re0  &#123; color: #09F; font-weight: bold; } /* variables */</li><li class="li1">.php .kw1  &#123; color: #069; font-weight: bold; } /* control statements? */</li><li class="li2">.php .kw4  &#123; color: #069; font-weight: bold; } /* bool? */</li><li class="li1">.php .co1  &#123; color: #FF8400 } /* Forward slash comments */</li></ol></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @KaleMcNaney Added html.  Note, depending on your resolution you may need to significantly reduce the width of your browser window manually to force a scrolling overflow condition.

Comment: @krish http://jsfiddle.net/947Pd/

Comment: @krish It is, the html source has what appears to be css as just plain text in it as well.

Comment: check this fiddle is it okay? http://jsfiddle.net/947Pd/4/

Answer (score 0):

The pre is fixed with 80% so the alternate color stops there we can extend the li with till the end by using the below styles.

```
    .li1 { background: #F5F5F5;width:200%; }
    .li2 { background: #eee;width:200%; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/947Pd/4)